# Tensorboard using Python 2.7, how to change it to Python 3?

Tags: python, python3, python-2.7

So I program a tensorflow program in python3, and can execute said scripts with python3, with the modules that I installed using pip3. But when using

```
tensorboard --logdir="./graphs" --port 6006
```

It is using Python2.7, and numpy is not installed, since I am not using Python 2. When installing numpy with pip (instead of pip3) it still does not work because AttributeErrors.

How can i tell tensorboard (and other programs) to use python3 with the pip3 modules, instead of python2.7?

Using `python3 tensorboard --logdir="./graphs" --port 6006` does not work, since python3 expects me to give it a script file.

Additional Information:
The tensorboard graph file has been created in the given path, from this code

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
tf.reset_default_graph()

a = tf.constant(2)
b = tf.constant(3)
c = tf.add(a, b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs', sess.graph)
    print(sess.run(c))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I use [miniconda](https://conda.io/en/master/miniconda.html) to create an environment in which I have control over the python (etc.) versions used.  There is also a python specific environment manager [pipenv](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/).

If you create an environment which only has python3 and which has your version of tensorflow & tensorboard, you may find it easier, especially as new software versions come out and you want to be able to control the versions in your environment.

Comment: That did worked, thanks. But I would like to run the scripts and programs outside of a virtual environment. I tried pipenv btw. I can run tensorboard in there with python3, but I still would like to just use the normal tensorboard installation thats already on my ubuntu, with python3 etc. Without any environments added

Comment: AFAIK there's no distribution which comes with tensorboard out-of-the-box, so your "normal tensorboard installation" must have been installed by you (or you're using a machine image with it installed already.  If the former, ask the people who provided the instructions you followed ... and if the latter, ask them why it's not working.  
  
Or, you could follow the crowd and use an environment (think container-light) ...

Comment: Tensorboard is being installed automatically when installing TensorFlow. So I have that since I installed TensorFlow. The Scripts are easy to run with python 3, by simply using "python3 script.py". But to run tensorflow to create a local webside with the graph, you cant specify it in python3 since python3 wants a file, and not a program command

Comment: Sorry for being a bit dense, but I've just looked in the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard) and it all looks like python to me, and looking at the tensorboard binary ... and it is 5 lines of python code which calls [tensorboard's main](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/main.py) function.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the @JeToJedno's answer.

TL;DR:  `$ python3 /usr/local/bin/tensorboard --logdir ...`

---

Explanation:

Since `/usr/local/bin/tensorboard` is a bash script that uses `/usr/local/bin/python` interpreter:

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from tensorboard.main import run_main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(run_main())
```

You can just run is with python of the desired version.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two python versions say python2.x and python3.x and say you want to use tensorboard for python 3.x. Go to the python 3.x directory and go to tensorboard directory. You will find the main.py file there. Open terminal from this location.
Type`python3 main.py --logdir path/to/log/directory`
That's it. Open the link given and watch your logs. Enjoy!